# How to define TypeScript types for chalk's tagged template literal?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, chalk

In chalk 2.0, it's possible to [use tagged strings](https://github.com/chalk/chalk#tagged-template-literal):

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
console.log(chalk`{bold some} text`);
```

How to amend chalk's [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/161f89426904e96567b77a71f302401cd58529e2/types/chalk/index.d.ts) to make TypeScript happy with it? Currently, I get:

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof Chalk' has no compatible call signatures.

Answer (score 0):

With Typescript, you should be using the import syntax vs require, and the error will go away.

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
```

Note that at the time you posted your question, there was also a template issue, but it has been fixed since.